# External sitemap.xml not showing up in search results

Tags: search, enterprise-search

I have some external sites that I want SharePoint to index.  There are some links that I need crawled that are not initially visible on the site because they are loaded via Ajax.  I have added these links to both the sitemap.xml files and also the urllist.txt file, but SharePoint doesn't seem to recognize or crawl the links on these files.

How can i get SharePoint to work in this way?

UPDATE : Just to clarify this external site is just a website, it isn't a SharePoint site.  Originally SharePoint had given me a message that it was ignoring the sitemap.xml because of a no-follow meta.  The only place I thought this could be was in the robots.txt file, so I removed it but I still am not having luck.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you store these links? If in a list, make sure the list is marked with Searchable in the Advanced Settings.

Run a crawl after changing these properties. Putting it in the sitemap doesn't really help.

C:\Marius

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The external site isn't a SharePoint site.  It's just a regular website.  It's crawling all the other pages ok, it's just not crawling the links in the sitemap.xml or urllist.txt file which I thought the SharePoint crawl engine did.

Comment: Ah, ok, then probably your problem comes from the actual file extensions that are considered in the crawling (under Crawlin - File Types) in the Search Service Application.

Comment: xml and txt are both listed under "File Types".  Is there somewhere else I need to configure them to follow the links?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up the content source at HTML web site and not SharePoint Site, then indexer will behave as bing/google.

Disadvantage with this method is that scheduler always will run a full crawl.

Comment: I have the content source set up as "Web Sites".